# Prove that $(1+x)^{\alpha}\geq 1+\alpha x$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $x \geq 0$ and $\alpha \geq 1$. Prove that $(1+x)^{\alpha}\geq 1+\alpha x$.

Since we aren't working with integers here, we are going to have to use other techniques. We take the log of both sides to get $\alpha \log(1+x) \geq \log(1+\alpha x) \implies \alpha \geq \dfrac{\log(1+\alpha x)} {\log(1+x)}$. Then how do I prove this?

Comment: This may help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Comment: hint: taylor expansion

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f(x) = \alpha\log(1+x) - \log(1+\alpha x)$ on $[0,\infty)$, and taking derivative $f'(x) = \dfrac{\alpha}{1+x} - \dfrac{\alpha}{1+\alpha x}\geq 0\Rightarrow f(x) \geq f(0) = 0$, hence the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

There is a generalisation of the binomial theorem for not integer power $\alpha$. So for $x \geq 0$ and $\alpha \geq 1$ we have that $\binom{\alpha}{k} \geq 1$ and it implies 
$$
(1+x)^{\alpha}=1+\binom{\alpha}{1}x+\binom{\alpha}{2} x^2+\cdots+ \geq 1+\alpha x.
$$

Comment: Binomial coefficients are defined via the gamma function here?

Comment: as usual $\binom{\alpha}{k}=\frac{\alpha (\alpha-1)\cdots (\alpha-(k-1))}{k!}$

Answer (score 0):

Define

$$f(x)=(1+x)^\alpha-\alpha x-1\implies f'(x)=\alpha(1+x)^{\alpha-1}-\alpha=0\iff$$

$$\iff (1+x)^{\alpha-1}=1\iff x=0$$

Also

$$f''(x)=\alpha(\alpha-1)(1+x)^{\alpha-2}\implies f''(0)=\alpha(\alpha-1)>0\implies $$

we have a minimal point when $\;x=0\;$ , and thus

$$\forall \,x\ge 0\;,\;\;f(x)\ge f(0)=0\;\;\color{green}\checkmark$$